# How to use the HashiCorp's Vault API in order to get all all the secret values from a directory with a single API call

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am using Postman to call the Vault API.

Right now I am doing an API call to this endpoint

> https://vault.something.com/v1/kv/data/ENV/DEV/secret1

I am passing in the body a roleId and secretId and in the headers the X-Vault-Namespace and X-Vault-Token and I am getting the value of the secret at this path.

I am also able to get all the keys by calling

> https://vault.something.com/v1/kv/metadata/ENV/DEV?list=true

I need to get the values of all the secrets from ENV/DEV/ using a single API call. Can you give me an idea? I got stuck in the existent documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can relax the requirement of "a single API call", then it can be simply achieved by following these two steps:

1. List all the keys in ENV/DEV/ using https://vault.something.com/v1/kv/metadata/ENV/DEV?list=true and put them into a list
2. Loop through the above list and for each item, call https://vault.something.com/v1/kv/data/ENV/DEV/ to extract all secrets and store in a dict secrets like secrets[] = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, Hashicorp has had an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/5275) on this subject for over four years and shows no sign of picking it up.

Many people have already built code to handle the recursion, and simply hammer the Vault API until a directory tree is fully explored. Check the GitHub issue linked above for helpful people that have posted their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Dec. 2023: From [issue 5275: "KV Engine: Recursively list keys"](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/5275#issuecomment-1848644661), [Maxime Genet](https://github.com/MochaCaffe)  proposes:

> I managed to implement a server-side search feature by adding a new API endpoint to the KV engine.
> This was done by modifying the existing KV secret plugin source code, which means that Vault needs to be recompiled locally.
>
> You can check my work here if you're interested for carrying further testing: https://github.com/MochaCaffe/vault-plugin-secrets-kv-search
>
> As I mentioned in the repository, please note that this is a highly experimental feature which could potentially lead to stability issues or vulnerabilities.
> In my case, the plugin was tested against a Vault instance with 6000+ secrets stored
>
> [image: https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/32551235/289309146-e2c6b06a-3109-4db5-a2f6-28d52ec07915.png?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.rZxHK24jpMfYwiBBrDaOzxObo7Yx7fmhvekA63LCV90]

---

Nov. 2023: From [issue 5275: "KV Engine: Recursively list keys"](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/5275#issuecomment-1792411030), [Shehab El-Deen Alalkamy](https://github.com/alalkamys) proposes:

> I had a use case to export all the KV secrets for a given path and save it locally in a `secrets.json` file.  I refactored it to export the secrets rather than list them.
>
> My Vault was sitting behind Cloudflare Zero trust, I adjusted the script to optionally pass CF_TOKEN to by pass Cloudflare as well, thought people might find this helpful for their use case:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# vault-kv-export.sh

set -eo pipefail

readonly ARB_TEMP_SECRETS_FILE="arbitrary_temp_secrets.json"
readonly TEMP_SECRETS_FILE="temp_secrets.json"
readonly SECRETS_FILE="secrets.json"

log() {
    local log_type="$1"
    local message="$2"
    local timestamp
    timestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    echo "[$log_type] [$timestamp] $message"
}

log_info() {
    log "INFO" "$1"
}

log_error() {
    log "ERROR" "$1"
    exit 1
}

traverse() {
    local path="$1"
    local result

    local headers=()
    if [[ -n "${CF_TOKEN}" ]]; then
        headers+=("-header" "cf-access-token=${CF_TOKEN}")
    fi

    result=$(vault kv list -format=json "${headers[@]}" "${path}" 2>&1) || log_error "Failed to list secrets: ${result}"

    while IFS= read -r secret; do
        if [[ "${secret}" == */ ]]; then
            traverse "${path}${secret}"
        else
            local secret_data
            secret_data=$(vault kv get -format=json "${headers[@]}" "${path}${secret}" | jq -r '.data') || log_error "Failed to get secret data: ${secret_data}"

            if [[ "${secret_data}" != "null" ]]; then
                echo "{\"path\":\"${path}${secret}\",\"value\":{\"data\":${secret_data}}}," >>"${ARB_TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}"
            fi
        fi
    done < <(echo "${result}" | jq -r '.[]')
}

main() {
    log_info "Starting secrets retrieval process."

    [[ -f "${ARB_TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}" ]] && rm -f "${ARB_TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}"
    [[ -f "${TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}" ]] && rm -f "${TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}"
    [[ -f "${SECRETS_FILE}" ]] && rm -f "${SECRETS_FILE}"

    if [[ -n "${CF_TOKEN}" ]]; then
        log_info "CF_TOKEN detected."
    else
        log_info "CF_TOKEN not provided. Headers will not be attached to Vault requests."
    fi

    local vaults
    if [[ "$1" ]]; then
        vaults=("${1%"/"}/")
        log_info "Retrieving all secrets under ${vaults[*]}.."
    else
        local headers=()
        if [[ -n "${CF_TOKEN}" ]]; then
            headers+=("-header" "cf-access-token=${CF_TOKEN}")
        fi
        log_info "No secret engine provided. Retrieving all secrets.."
        result=$(vault secrets list -format=json "${headers[@]}" 2>&1) || log_error "Failed to list secrets engines: ${result}"
        mapfile -t vaults < <(echo "${result}" | jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.value.type=="kv") | .key')
    fi

    for vault in "${vaults[@]}"; do
        traverse "${vault}"
    done

    echo "[" >"${TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}"
    sed '$s/,$//' "${ARB_TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}" >>"${TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}"
    echo "]" >>"${TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}"

    jq . "${TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}" >"${SECRETS_FILE}"
    rm "${ARB_TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}" "${TEMP_SECRETS_FILE}"

    log_info "Secrets retrieval completed and saved to ${SECRETS_FILE}"
}

[[ "$0" == "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]] && main "$@"
```

A sample output:

```bash
$ ./vault-kv-export.sh secret2/confluent_cloud

[INFO] [2023-11-03 15:06:15] Starting secrets retrieval process.
[INFO] [2023-11-03 15:06:15] CF_TOKEN detected.
[INFO] [2023-11-03 15:06:15] Retrieving all secrets under secret2/confluent_cloud/..
[INFO] [2023-11-03 15:06:27] Secrets retrieval completed and saved to secrets.json
```

With:

```bash
$ cat secrets.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "path": "secret2/confluent_cloud/global-creds",
    "value": {
      "data": {
        "data": {
          "confluent_cloud_token": "REDACTED"
        },
        "metadata": {
          "created_time": "2023-11-02T13:14:09.616943342Z",
          "custom_metadata": null,
          "deletion_time": "",
          "destroyed": false,
          "version": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "path": "secret2/confluent_cloud/service/credentials",
    "value": {
      "data": {
        "data": {
          "api_key": "REDACTED",
          "api_secret": "REDACTED"
        },
        "metadata": {
          "created_time": "2023-11-02T13:14:10.336792836Z",
          "custom_metadata": null,
          "deletion_time": "",
          "destroyed": false,
          "version": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
```